# Let's not throw money at lawyers

Tags: phrase-requests, business-language, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for telling my client to leave the lawyers to one side and sign a contract later on in the process -- something like "Let's not throw money at lawyers at this stage"?

Thanks,

Assaf.

Comment: Do not feed the sharks. Yet.

Comment: I thought *Let's not throw money at lawyers* is already an idiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to negotiate an agreement without a lawyer, it's fine to say, *Let's not throw money away on lawyers just yet.*

Answer (score 2):

A few come to mind:

> Let's not pay a king's ransom for unnecessary litigation!
>
> At this stage, a lawyer isn't worth a red cent.
>
> We're pouring money right down the drain!
>
> Let's not burn a hole in our pockets if we don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

"The first thing we do, let's kill all the lawyers".

William Shakespeare, *Henry The Sixth,* Part 2 Act 4, scene 2, 71–78

(Old problem.)

Comment: Away with him, I say! hang him with his pen and
ink-horn about his neck.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

Don't waste the time.